# Can awk help detect sequence in a file?

Tags: sed, awk, grep

Ok, this is an easy one for the Pro's here; yet the answer has eluded me thus far...

Contents of my file contain comma separated values from which I need to extract a number. My problem is the sequence of surrounding values is important to return the correct number.

Example file contents:

```
car, 00, tar
foo, 01, bar
bar, 02, foo
foo, 04, car
```

Perhaps using awk or sed, help me to assign variable var to 01 based on the fact that foo appears before bar in the line. Assigning it to 02 would be wrong since bar appears before foo.

Apologies in advance if this is duplicate... I did search here and several other places online; thanks in advance! Also, I'm still trying to get the formatting correct using the various code and tag parms.

Comment: consider editing your question to include minimal sample data that illustrates cases that should be processed VS not processed AND then show the expected output from that input. Note the `{}` tool at the top of the edit box to format selected text for better legibility. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I follow your question, but for searching a pattern and returning specific column value can be done easliy with `awk`.

You can play around with the following idea:

```
$ cat file
car, 00, tar
foo, 01, bar
bar, 02, foo
```

```
$ var=$(awk -F', ' '$1=="foo"{print $2}' file)
```

```
$ echo "$var"
01
```

Comment: Ah, quite good! I need to detect the presence of both foo and bar together, and in that sequence before assigning var to 01. So for example if file contained line: foo, 04, car then it would not return 04, instead just 01. does that make sense?

Comment: @user3338443 Sure you can do `var=$(awk -F', ' '$1=="foo" && $3=="bar" {print $2}' file)`